# WPF TextBox selected text does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a readonly TextBox control with a static resource, looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="MyEditTextEditor">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding Path=TextEditorFontFamily, ElementName=LogViewerProperty}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding Path=TextEditorFontWeight, ElementName=LogViewerProperty}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Path=TextEditorFontSize, ElementName=LogViewerProperty}" />
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="{Binding Path=TextEditorFontStyle, ElementName=LogViewerProperty}" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="{Binding Path=WordWrapping, ElementName=LogViewerProperty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToTextWrap}}" />
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Message, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
              <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="-3,-1"/>
              </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
              <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.4" Color="{Binding Source={x:Reference LogViewerProperty}, Path=TextEditorSelectionColor}" />
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It's embedded into a ListBox. All works fine, but when I want to get the selected text, the property is always string.Empty. The SelectionChanged event works perfect. Any suggestions? At the moment I do not know, why the SelectedText is string.Empty.

Here is the SelectionChanged event

```
private void ReadOnlyEditor_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  LOG.Debug("Current text {3}; selection {0} length {1}, start {2}", readOnlyEditor.SelectedText, readOnlyEditor.SelectionLength, readOnlyEditor.SelectionStart, readOnlyEditor.Text);
}
```

And yes, the text is selected in the control, but the property is empty. In readOnlyEditor.Text exists the right text.

Comment: SelectedText is the text that is literally selected. As in the text that is highlighted. If nothing is selected then it will return empty string. Are you sure you don't just want the Text?

Comment: Have you tried binding the `SelectedText` of the TextBox in the template to the `SelectedText`? As in `SelectedText="{TemplateBinding SelectedText}"` on the template TextBox.

Comment: Unfortunately is SelectedText not a Dependency property - this kind of binding is not possible.

Comment: I doubt it's a clever idea to have a TextBox in the ControlTemplate of a TextBox.

Comment: Aah, this was a good hint, thank you! I comment out the part ControlTemplate and tried again. Now it works!

Comment: The issue is fixed, see above. The problem was the inline ControlTemplate definition.

Answer (score 0):

Put your data binding into the ListBoxItem, then call the data from the ListBoxItem. Then the whole ListBoxItem is selectable. e.g.

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListItemSelected" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelectedTextTemplate}">  
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
           .../...
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Build your data template or control template outside of the ListBox e.g.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTextTemplate">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedText}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```